# How do I set a click action on zenity --notification?

Tags: notification, zenity

Running

```
echo "message:hi" | zenity --notification --listen
```

I can click the bubble and it disappears. The zenity program keeps running until I Ctrl-C. Is there a way to "catch" the click and make some program run if the bubble is clicked before it goes away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request to perform an action when you click on the Zenity notification icon is a [long standing request](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity).

According to the [associated bug-report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=310001), it was proposed to perform this action when you pass a parameter like `--cmd=` - an example use-case was to invoke the terminal window when the notification was clicked i.e. by passing the parameter `--cmd=gnome-terminal`

However, this is still outstanding, awaiting for a budding coder to take this forward.

Comment: Note: there's a fork at https://code.google.com/p/yad that supposedly deals with some of the zenity bug reports